# O que significa o arroba (@) em variáveis no Ruby?

Tags: ruby

O que significa arroba (@) na frente de variáveis no Ruby?

Por exemplo

```
@s = gets.to_i
```

Comment: Acredito que você tem potencial para escrever um título muito melhor que esse. Qualquer coisa, pode ver algumas discussões no [meta] sobre como [elaborar um bom título](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=t%C3%ADtulo)

Comment: Caro Misaee, editei sua pergunta, observe a diferença do titulo inicial para o titulo atual, isto ajuda as pessoas entenderem a sua pergunta, é totalmente redundante escrever "ajuda", todos vem buscando ajuda aqui no site, coloque foco em descrever o problema, assim desperta  interesse nas pessoas em lhe ajudar e já deixa o problema mais claro antes mesmo de alguém entrar na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Significa que o scopo dessa variável, ou seja o limite que ela pode ser acessada é de dentro de uma classe. Ela é uma váriavel de instância.

Esse seu código é só uma linha fica difícil explicar só com essa linha.
Mas segue o exemplo abaixo

```
class Pessoa
   def initialize(nome, sobrenome)
     contador_de_letras_do_nome = nome.size
     @nome = nome
     @sobrenome = sobrenome
   end

   def nome_completo
     @nome + @sobrenome
   end
end
```

No exemplo acima a classe pessoa pode acessar dentro dela as váriaveis
`@nome` e `@sobrenome`. Eleas inclusive são usadas dentro no método `nome_compleo`.

Porém a variável `contador_de_letras_do_nome` não pode ser acessada dentro do método `nome_compleo` se por acaso eu precisasse. Pois essa várial não tem o `@`, ou seja, o escopo dela é de método.

Você pode ver mais nesse post.
[ruby várial escopo](https://wmagician.wordpress.com/2008/01/26/ruby-variaveis/)